# Como puedo heredar fragmentos

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment

Buen dia Compañeros, no se si la pregunta estara bien formulada, tengo un Fragment principal que tiene un mapa y 5 botones cada uno con su OnclickListener, tengo mucho codigo en dicho fragment, lo cual quiero segmentar, habrá alguna manera de llevar esos metodos onclick a otros fragment o clases para solamente dejar los metodos de GoogleMap en mi fragment principal.

Solicito de ayuda, por favor.

Este es mi FragmentPrincipal

```
public class SolicitudesFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

public View onCreateView(@NonNull final LayoutInflater inflater,
                             final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mapa_solicitudes, container, false);
        final SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.mapSolicitudes);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

 form_solicitudes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Dialog dialogo = new Dialog(getContext());
                dialogo.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialogo.setCancelable(false);
                dialogo.setContentView(R.layout.activity_destino);
                dialogo.show();

                final EditText direccion = (EditText) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.direccion_recogida);
                Button btn_enviar = (Button) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.btn_enviar);
                btn_enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        direccion_s = direccion.getText().toString().trim();
                        if(direccion_s.length()==0){
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Campo Obligatorio: Dirección", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }else{

                            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
                            progressDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.logocopp);
                            progressDialog.setTitle("Taxi Primero");
                            progressDialog.setMessage("Su Solicitud ha sido procesada, favor espere la confirmación del servicio");
                            progressDialog.show();
                            Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-2.1172431, -79.892731);
                                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
                                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 14));
                                    form_solicitudes.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    dialogo.dismiss();
                                }
                            },4000);
                        }//fin del else
                    }
                });//fin del setOnclickListener
        return view;
    }// fin del método OnCreateView
```

este es uno de los metodos onclick, los otros 4 son parecidos, por eso no los puse, este boton **form_solicitudes** que tiene el **OnclickListener**, quiero llevarlo a otro fragment o clase, lo he intentado creando un **FragmentBlank** que extiende del Fragment principal **SolicitudesFragment** pero sin embargo no me reconoce el OnclickListener, llevo 2 dias con esto y no puedo solucionarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tony, lo que debes hacer es crear una nueva clase dentro del mismo paquete
en el que esta tu fragmento, para ello das click derecho en el paquete en la barra de 
proyectos, y creas una nueva clase, vas a querer crear una clase para cada boton.

Como ves en la imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Luego de eso aparecera un dialogo, en el cual nombraras la clase, en este caso la nombraremos Boton1Click y luego le das OK. 
Una vez se abre el archivo de la clase Boton1Click, dentro de esta clase, implementaras el View.OnClickListener, declararas, las variables globales que utilizabas en tu app para poder pasarlas en un constructor con lo cual te quedaria el siguiente codigo:

```
import android.view.View;

public class Boton1Click implements View.OnClickListener {
    View view;
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

    Boton1Click(View view, SupportMapFragment mapFragment) {
        this.view = view;
        this.mapFragment = mapFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final Dialog dialogo = new Dialog(getContext());
        dialogo.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialogo.setCancelable(false);
        dialogo.setContentView(R.layout.activity_destino);
        dialogo.show();

        final EditText direccion = (EditText) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.direccion_recogida);
        Button btn_enviar = (Button) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.btn_enviar);
        btn_enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String direccion_s = direccion.getText().toString().trim();
                if (direccion_s.length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Campo Obligatorio: Dirección", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {

                    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
                    progressDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.logocopp);
                    progressDialog.setTitle("Taxi Primero");
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Su Solicitud ha sido procesada, favor espere la confirmación del servicio");
                    progressDialog.show();
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-2.1172431, -79.892731);
                            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
                            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 14));
                            form_solicitudes.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            dialogo.dismiss();
                        }
                    }, 4000);
                }//fin del else
            }
        });//fin del setOnclickListener
    }
}
```

Luego tu codigo original quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
public class SolicitudesFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull final LayoutInflater inflater,
                             final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mapa_solicitudes, container, false);
        final SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.mapSolicitudes);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        form_solicitudes.setOnClickListener(new Boton1Click(view,mapFragment));
        return view;// fin del método OnCreateView
        }
    }
}
```

Luego, debes hacer lo mismo con tus 4 botones, para que todos queden en archivos separados.

NOTA: Si lo que sucede es que el codigo se ve engorroso, pero realmente no lo quieres separar en distintos archivos, puedes darle a minimizar en la parte izquierda del editor de texto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estimado, Muchisimas Gracias funciono...!!!  a la perfección, ahora asi a dormir un rato jajaja,  Saludos.